# replacing "name" with "id" in a gallery (javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery, onmouseover

I'm using this gallery in a schoolproject: http://html-tuts.com/html-photo-gallery-simple-javascript/.
I got it to work, but when I validate it (using: http://validator.w3.org/)
I get an error saying i should replace all "name" attributes with "id" attributes. However doing so stops my gallery from working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html:

```
<div class="gallery">
                <h2 class="h2Fotos">Badkamers:</h2>
                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer1.src" name="badkamer1" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_01.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer2.src" name="badkamer2" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_02.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer3.src" name="badkamer3" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_03.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer4.src" name="badkamer4" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_04.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer5.src" name="badkamer5" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_05.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer6.src" name="badkamer6" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_06.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer7.src" name="badkamer7" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_07.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer8.src" name="badkamer8" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_08.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer9.src" name="badkamer9" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_09.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer10.src" name="badkamer10" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_10.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer11.src" name="badkamer11" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_11.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer12.src" name="badkamer12" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_12.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer13.src" name="badkamer13" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_13.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                    <img onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer14.src" name="badkamer14" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_14.jpg" alt="badkamer" />
                </div>
                <div class="preview1">
                    <img name="preview1" src="images/diensten/badkamers/badkamer_01.jpg" alt="badkamer"/>
                </div>
```

Comment: What's this: `<img ="preview1" src="i... />`? Notice that with `id`s you usually use `getElementById()` method to get a reference to an element.

Comment: That's the big image. When you hover over the thumbnails this images changes its src to the src of the thumbnail.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error to me ...

Comment: @Teemu touche! I only mentioned/noticed the semantic error.

Comment: Can it be a syntax error if it works? it only stops working when i replace "name" with "id".  I think i need to change onmouseover="preview1.src=badkamer1.src" to something else...

Comment: Just noticed i copy/pasted my code wrong... edited my question

Comment: Change all the `name` to `id`, then use `getElementById()` like Temmu mentioned to change the `src` attribute of the `preview1`

Comment: @Seth I just edited my answer. Check out the JSFiddle and let me know if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid in this case does not constitute any syntax error, but rather a semantic invalidity. You have two choice:

1. Keep the name attribute and disregard the validator because as you mentioned, the code works.
2. Satisfy the validator and go with an id or even a class

> The HTML 4.0 Specification did not allow a NAME attribute for a FORM
>   or IMG element. This means that such attributes give validation errors
>   when validating against any HTML 4.0 DTD. However, the HTML 4.01
>   Specification (approved 1999-12-24), which contains several changes
>   (usually small ones) as compared with HTML 4.0, allows the NAME
>   attribute for those FORM and for IMG elements. Thus, you can now use
>   the following document type declaration if you use those attributes
>   [Source](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/javascript.html#nameattr)
>
> In HTML5, The name attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use the
>   id attribute instead. [Source](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/img.html)

---

**EDIT** Here is the javascript logic you can use. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/ch5a3u4v/1/)

```
<div class="gallery">
 <h2 class="h2Fotos">Thumbnails:</h2>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview1').src=this.src" 
    id="badkamer1" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f56600" alt="badkamer1" />

    <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview1').src=this.src" 
    id="badkamer2" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/17c423" alt="badkamer2" />

    <img onmouseover="getElementById('preview1').src=this.src" 
    id="badkamer3" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/9800ff" alt="badkamer2" />

    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <img id="preview1" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="badkamer" />
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to go with an "id", but my knowledge of javascript is very limited and i can't figure out how to change it so it works with an "id" attribute. I can replace all "name" attributes with "id", but then my gallery stops working. Thank you for your reply in any case :)

Comment: @ Seth My best advice is to use a javascript slider such as [Jssor](http://www.jssor.com/) with both informative documentation and flexible customization. This is my slider of choice and it doesn't violate semantic javascript aka it validates.

Comment: I normally would, but i have to be able to explain any javascript i use. So i have to keep it as basic as possible.

Comment: @Seth  provide your javascript, then make a reasonable attempt at solving the problem, showing/explaining your process, then if you still have problems and need help...let us know.

Comment: this is all i have. I don't have any other javascript. i'm ok at HTML and CSS but i have never in my life used any javascript. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Seth I understand your frustration. I didn't know what javascript was a year ago and now I do it for a living, but you do need to understand that StackOverflow is a forum for "programmers and programming enthusiasts". We are not here to do your homework, rather to point you in the right direction, help, and induce learning.

Comment: @Seth I can recommend resources to help you learn javascript if you'd like, then after you make a stab at it, I can guide you the remainder of the way.